# Parse Cloud Code Can't Use new command for Cloud Code Setting

Tags: parse-platform

After installing cloud code , I was ok with parse new command in early day. Now, parse new command is not working as well.Show me the following error .

$ parse new MyCloudCode
unexpected arguments:[MyCloudCode]

Creates a new Parse app and adds Cloud Code to an existing Parse app.

Usage: 
  parse new [flags]

Global Flags:
  -h, --help=false: help for new

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The documentation must be out of date.  If you use the command without the name, like this:

`$parse new`

Then, it will prompt you for email/password and afterwards, you can name the directory "MyCloudCode" or whatever you'd like.

Comment: Great !! Useful Answer